# Why was this character paid?

Tags: the-dresden-files

Listening to *Blood Rites* again, and noticed something for the first time. At the end, Harry's debt to a certain mercenary is paid for him. But the character who did it would not have known that Harry had that debt at all, nor to whom.  At least, as of when it would have been paid, through only information available to anyone but Harry or Murphy is a dollar figure and a bank account number. Seems like scant information to assume it represents an IOU.  Am I missing a key story detail?  On camera at least, Harry doesn't ever tell him about hiring a mercenary or why, afaik

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Thomas was around long enough to figure it out.**

In the last chapter of *Blood Rites*, Harry brings Thomas to his basement home after clearing the air with Lara and his final visit to Justine. The very next paragraph is Harry trying to scare up money for the rest of the day to pay Kincaid, which of course, fails. So Thomas was definitely hanging around while Harry tried rather frantically to pay a bill... and then he found the "bill", Kincaid's card.  They're family, he has money, that's enough.

Thomas may also have gotten a brief summary of the lair raid from Murphy while they were taking turns trying to take care of Harry's charbroiled hand.  Murphy wouldn't know about Kincaid's fees, but could say enough about what happened that Thomas would know a highly professional and lethal (and therefore expensive) mercenary was involved.  That's not explicitly shown, but it might have been another way he put the details together.